# Did noted 17th century poet Katherine Philips make a grammatical error?

Tags: pronouns, poetry, personal-pronouns, grammatical-case, rhymes

Does the last line of the first stanza of Katherine Philips's poem, *To Mrs. M. A. at parting* have a grammatical error?

It's surprising that a renowned poet and translator at that time would use the wrong pronoun to fit the rhyme.  Or am I mistaken here?

> I
>    HAVE examin'd and do find,
>   Of all that favour me,
>   There's none I grieve to leave behind
>   But only, only thee.
>   To part with thee I needs must die,
>   **Could parting sep'rate thee and I.**

Would the poet's contemporaries have seen the construction as ungrammatical or non-standard (though acceptable *in a poem*) or was it more generally acceptable then than it is now?

If you think the subjective first-person singular pronoun 
"I" was only used in the last line due to "poetic license," please post that as an answer and provide evidence that the structure was considered ungrammatical outside of poetic contexts at the time the poem was written.

Comment: Poetic license.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a poem. The poetic license covers deviations from 'standard' or 'grammatical' English.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey: the error is 'I' for 'me'.

Comment: It wouldn't be surprising if a famous 17th century poet didn't conform to 21st century grammar. Her grammar books were probably quite outdated, and she couldn't look up things on the internet.

Comment: It's deliberate usage but not just to make it rhyme. What she was doing was echoing the previous line by reversing the word order. The fact that the grammar then became non-standard was part of the emphasis and the really clever word play.

Comment: To hell with the grammar.  The poem brought tears to my eyes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a poem, where poetic license reigns.

Comment: @HotLicks, how are questions about English language grammar in poems off topic? 'Poetic license' is any 'license' taken, in any writing or art, whereby deviations from "recognized forms or rules", are indulged for the sake of effect. The 'poetic license' (so-called), when referring to poetry (as opposed to, for example, liberties taken with perspective in visual artwork), generally refers to metrical deviations from standard metrical forms, not grammatical deviations in service of rhyme, which latter are usually (except in humorous or dialectal poetry) regarded as unmitigated flaws.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because grammaticality is ill-defined nowadays, and was more fluid (and acceptability harder to research) in those days.

Comment: @JEL - Until it was edited 59 minutes ago, the question asked if there was a syntax error in the poem.  "Poetic license" means that such a syntax error (if there is one) is irrelevant.  Hence the question is, if not completely off-topic, then poorly formed.

Comment: @HotLicks: When did it say anything about syntax? All I added with the edit is the last paragraph. The possible existence of "poetic license" does not negate the question. The lines can still be evaluated for grammaticality as ordinary English sentences.

Comment: @suməlic - The OP said "It's surprising that a renowned poet and translator at that time would use the wrong pronoun to fit the rhyme."  That's exactly what poetic license is.  Given that, and given that we cannot evaluate the bounds of poetic license, especially of a renowned poet, the question is effectively invalid.  You then changed the question with your edit.

Comment: @HotLicks: It's not asking for an evaluation of the bounds of poetic license. It's asking for an evaluation that ignores poetic license: does she "use the wrong pronoun to fit the rhyme" (possible, due to poetic license) or does she use a form of the pronoun that would be considered grammatical in other contexts as well?

Comment: @suməlic - As modified, yes.  That's not what it asked originally.

Comment: [But I love she and she loves me; Enraptured are the both of we. Yes, I love she and she loves I, And will through all eternitye.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f0Wa_tnvyag)

Answer (score 13):

At the time Philips wrote the poem, around the middle of the 17th century, the use of 'I' as the object of a verb or preposition was (sometimes) considered grammatical. As noted in the entry under **I**, *pron.* and *n.*<sup>2</sup>, **A.II.2a**, *OED Online*,

> This has been common at various times (esp. towards the end of the 16th and in the 17th cent., and from the mid 20th cent. onwards); it has been considered ungrammatical since the 18th cent.
>
> ["I, pron. and n.2". *OED Online*. September 2016. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/90671 (accessed September 28, 2016).]

As defined in **A.II.2a**, the pronoun 'I' is

> Used for the objective case after a verb or preposition when separated from the governing word by other words (*esp.* in coordinate constructions with another pronoun and *and*).
>
> (op. cit.)

Among the attestations are three from Shakespeare in the early 1600s (*Merchant of Venice*, *Sonnets* and *As You Like It*), as well as this from [*The Nicholas Papers*](https://archive.org/stream/thenicholaspaper01camduoft#page/136/mode/2up/search/%22to+give+you+and+I%22) in 1649:

> [image: example: "to give you and I"]

Two attestations from [*The provok'd wife*](https://archive.org/details/provokdwifecomed00vanbuoft) (1697) make the case for uses in the latter half of the 1600s:

> [image: example: "light upon Heartfree and I"]
>
> ([*The provok'd wife*](https://archive.org/stream/provokdwifecomed00vanbuoft#page/n71/mode/2up/search/%22light+upon%22), J. Vanbrugh)
>
> [image: example: "between you and I"]
>
> ([op. cit.](https://archive.org/stream/provokdwifecomed00vanbuoft#page/n27/mode/2up/search/%22Between+you+and+I%22))

Comment: So when I change the lyrics of Pat-a-Cake to "...and mark it with a Y/and throw it in the oven for Y___ and I!" I could claim to be archaic, rather than just ungrammatical/non-standard/taking poetic license? (This has seriously been on my mind; quite a timely question for me as my baby Y___ is now 6 months old.)

Comment: @1006a, sure you could. Whoever you're talking to might not buy your claim, but that's neither here nor there. Grammar, being a matter of established usage *at the time of use*, and being changeable over time, is correct or incorrect depending on when it is used (or on, as you suggest, a simulated time period). If the use in this poem was an established use when the poem was written, the poem was not ungrammatical at the time, however much it may be considered ungrammatical if written now.

Comment: @1006a, after looking into it a bit more (you understand the following is somewhat tongue-in-cheek, right?), your revision of "Pattycake" might run afoul of pedants whining about anacronism. This is because the first recorded version from 1698 is not entirely suitable, while the second is from around 1765, when the objective 'I' was probably considered ungrammatical. I suggest you avoid the problem this by claiming yours is a 'lost' first version from the late 1600s.